# How to list Github public repositories of a programming language with Pagination

Tags: github, pagination, repository

I am trying to get Github public repositories of a programming language with pagination. So far, I've been able to fetch only 100 repositories using this url `https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/Go?language=GO&page=2&per_page=25`.

Where **page** and **per_page** parameters are not working and it gives me only static 100 results regardless of parameter values. I also have tried "**since**" parameter but no luck. Please help me how can I do pagination on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has this to say about the [legacy API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/legacy/#legacy-search-api-is-deprecated):

> The Legacy Search API (described below) is [deprecated](https://developer.github.com/v3/versions/#v3-deprecations) and is scheduled for removal in the next major version of the API.
>
> We recommend using the [v3 Search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/) instead. It contains new endpoints and much more functionality.

If you have a choice, try using the v3 [search repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) endpoint:

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:go&page=3&per_page=100
```

Comment: Thank u @Chris for prompt response. Just want to know one more thing that whats difference between using =go and :go as a value of parameter language? Can't I use standard arg=val format? Thanks

Comment: There is a huge difference in results as well when I use =go instead of :go

Comment: @umali, in this case you should only use `language:go`. If you look at the documentation for that endpoint you will see that it only accepts three arguments, `q`, `sort` and `order`, in addition to standard GitHub API arguments like `per_page`. [`language:go`](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/#search-based-on-the-main-language-of-a-repository) is _part of the argument_ to the query (`q`) parameter, which [uses `:` for its own arguments](https://help.github.com/articles/search-syntax/).